# How to cancel orders using payment method in magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I am creating an Open Source Extension for Magento. Its in very early stages. I am struggling with cancel orders problem. I found some solution here

[Magento - How can I run code when my order is canceled or refunded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796384/magento-how-can-i-run-code-when-my-order-is-canceled-or-refunded).

But whenever I cancel an order it calls neither void (in case of only Authorize payment action) nor refund (in case of authorize-capture payment action).

When I use capture-refund, It says the order cannot be cancelled.

When I use authorize-void, It say's the order have been cancelled. But the Void() function wasn't called at all. I kept some Mage::Log() functions inside. Which are not shown in Log file.

I don't understand what is wrong.

Here is the code.
This is payment method model

```
<?php 
class Package_Cashondelivery_Model_Createorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'cashondelivery';
    protected $_canCapture = true;
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
    protected $_canFetchTransactionInfo     = true;
    protected $_isGateway                   = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal = true;
    protected $_canVoid    = true;
    protected $_canRefund = true;

    public function validate()
    {

        $paymentInfo = $this->getInfoInstance();
         if ($paymentInfo instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment) {
             $postCode = $paymentInfo->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();

         } 
         else {
             $postCode = $paymentInfo->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
         }
         $res=Api->validatePostCode($postCode);
         $r = $res=='false'? FALSE : TRUE; 
         if (!$r) {
             Mage::throwException($this->_getHelper()->__('Sorry ! Service is not available in your area'));
         }
         return $this;
    }

    public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
    {
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        #This is working fine
        $transactionId = Api->someCall();
        $payment->setTransactionId();
       ------------------------------- 
       -------------------------------
       -------------------------------
       -------------------------------
       -------------------------------
       -------------------------------
        return $this;
    }

    public function void(Varien_Object $payment)
    {
        if (!$this->canVoid($payment)) {
            Mage::throwException($this->_getHelper()->__('Void action is not available.'));
        }
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        Mage::Log('Starting Void here....');
        $transactionId = $Payment->getTransactionId();
        Api->cancelOrder($transactionId);
        return $this;
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
        -------------------------------
    }
}
?>
```

Here is config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <Package_Cashondelivery>
<!-- declare module's version information for database updates -->
          <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Package_Cashondelivery>
    </modules>
    <global>
<!-- declare model group for new module -->
        <models>
<!-- model group alias to be used in Mage::getModel('newmodule/...') -->
            <cashondelivery>
<!-- base class name for the model group -->
                <class>Package_Cashondelivery_Model</class>
            </cashondelivery>    
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <cashondelivery>
                <class>Package_Cashondelivery_Helper</class>
            </cashondelivery>
        </helpers> 
<!-- declare resource setup for new module -->
        <resources>
<!-- resource identifier -->
            <cashondelivery_setup>
<!-- specify that this resource is a setup resource and used for upgrades -->
                <setup>
<!-- which module to look for install/upgrade files in -->
                    <module>Package_Cashondelivery</module>
                </setup>
<!-- specify database connection for this resource -->
                <connection>
<!-- do not create new connection, use predefined core setup connection -->
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </cashondelivery_setup>
            <cashondelivery_write>
                <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </cashondelivery_write>
            <cashondelivery_read>
               <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
            </cashondelivery_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
<!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
    <default>
        <payment>
            <cashondelivery>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>cashondelivery/createorder</model>
                <order_status>Processing</order_status>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <title>Cash On Delivery</title>
                <example_uri>services.example.com</example_uri>
            </cashondelivery>
         </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Anybody has any idea why this happens and how to resolve.

Comment: Is there anyone here who can help me please....

Comment: do you found a solution? I have exact the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have enough "experience" to just comment, so I'll post this as an answer instead.

Can you verify the order is in the proper state before canceling? For example, some orders are auto processed, like software downloads. Credit card charging, and product distribution can all be done automatically, then I doubt it lets you cancel. Can you verify the order is still pending?

Comment: I am trying to cancel an order that was created by same payment method.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Of course its the same payment method, we're only talking about 1 order. Can you explain further?

Comment: When I place order the authorize method is called...authorize method makes a rest api call and gets a response. In response I get and unique reference Id from Api which I store as transactionId in Magento. After the order is succesful I go select the same order and try to cancel. It shows order cancelled successfully but the API call in Void() function didn't happen. This what I didn't understand the reason

Comment: May I know what are the mandatory flags like canVoid, canCancel etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be able to '**Cancel**' or '**Void**' an order that has not been captured. i.e. an order that doesn't have an associated invoice.

If you want to **refund** a captured order, then this should be done by creating a **creditmemo** on the **invoice**.

For the issue of your payment method's **void function** not being called - you should set up an IDE like **Netbeans**, using **X-Debug**, and put a break point in the first line of the **cancelAction** and **voidPaymentAction** functions in **Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController**. This way you can step through the code and see where the issue is.

For example, the route to **void** should be something like...

**Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController**->**voidPaymentAction**:629
**Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment**->**void**:602
**Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment**->**_void**:1088
**Package_Cashondelivery_Model_Createorder**->**void**:

So **if you don't want to get into using a proper debugging environment**, then put your log statements along that path and check all the conditions are valid to call your payment method's void function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Magento indeed does not call either Void, nor Refund when you press cancel. When you press void it runs the void method, and when you click on refund it calls the refund method. And guess what, when you press on cancel, it actually calls the cancel method.

I agree that when you press cancel you actually want to void the authorization, but it comes handy to have separate methods just in case you would like to do something else too. So you could do something like this:

```
/*
 * Your class stuff
 */

public function cancel(Varien_Object $payment){

    // void the order if canceled
    $this->void($payment);

    return $this;
}

public function void(Varien_Object $payment){

    /* Whatever you call to void a payment in your gateway */

}
```